# Conservation of momentum with antiparticle annihilation

Tags: particle-physics, momentum, conservation-laws, antimatter

I'm confused about how momentum can be conserved when a particle and its antiparticle collide. For example, if an electron and positron collide and annihilate to form two photons, then there should be a change in momentum since photons have no mass and therefore can't have momentum since p = mv. Surely I'm missing something. Right?

Comment: "Surely I'm missing something. Right?" Yes. Photons can have momentum, and it depends on their wavelength $\lambda$. $p(\lambda) =\frac{h}{\lambda}$. This is a quantum phenomenon (hence the appearance of Planck's constant $h$).

Comment: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/College_Physics/College_Physics_1e_(OpenStax)/29%3A_Introduction_to_Quantum_Physics/29.04%3A_Photon_Momentum

Comment: An example of the confusion that ensues when rest mass is fashionably called mass.

Comment: The electron and positron in the initial state also fail to obey $p = mv$. The way to resolve this confusion is to learn relativity. Not revert to an old definition of mass which makes learning relativity harder.

Comment: @ConnorBehan "Makes learning relativity harder" is a matter of opinion. When physics pedagogy has declined to the point that MIT students can't figure out how to connect a light bulb to a battery, I question the judgement of our pedagogues.

Answer (score 2):

> photons have no mass and therefore can't have momentum since p = mv.

The relationship between mass, energy, and momentum is $$m^2 c^2 = E^2/c^2 - p^2$$ Photons have no mass, so their momentum is $$p=E/c$$

> I'm confused about how momentum can be conserved when a particle and its antiparticle collide. For example, if an electron and positron collide and annihilate to form two photons

This is easiest to analyze using the four-momentum which is given by $$P=(E/c,\vec p)$$ The conservation of the four-momentum encapsulates both the conservation of energy and the conservation of momentum. I will use units where energy is measured in $\mathrm{MeV}$, momentum is measured in units of $\mathrm{MeV}/c$, and mass is measured in units of $\mathrm{MeV}/c^2$. Assuming that the initial positron and electron are approximately at rest we get $$P_{e^+} + P_{e^-}=P_{\gamma_1}+P_{\gamma_2}$$$$(0.511/c,0)+(0.511/c,0) = (E/c,E/c)+(E/c,-E/c)$$$$E=0.511\mathrm{\ MeV}$$